# Google map autocomplete search box not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a search box to autocomplete that will make the google map go to the location in the search box. So far not having much luck figuring out why it is not working.

----------HTML

```
<div class="input-group location" >
         <input type="text" id="location" placeholder="Enter Location">
         <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker geolocation" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Find my position"></i></span>
</div>
```

----------javascript

```
    var input = document.getElementById('#location') ;
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, {
        types: ["geocode"]
    });

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() 
    {
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
            map.setZoom(14);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(14);
        }

        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        //marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && 
                 place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1] && 
                 place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2] && 
                 place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working, only issue is with the input element you get, you have used # tag to get input, here is your working code,

[Your Code](https://jsfiddle.net/xj2d77be/7/)

need to change is,

`var input = document.getElementById('location');`  //remove # tag